# Copy file in maven assembly

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin

I am building one maven assembly. The structure is like this:

```
src
  main
    server
      app1
      app2
      app3
    client
      app1
      app2
      app3
    common
      server.xml
```

The assembly makes the output as:

```
server.zip
  app1
  app2
  app3
```

I want to include `server.xml` in each of the output folders for apps. So my output should be:

```
server.zip
  app1
    server.xml  
  app2
    server.xml  
  app3
    server.xml
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to copy the file `server.xml` multiple times, by declaring it multiple times in the `assembly.xml`. Here's a sample assembly descriptor:

```xml
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.3" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.3 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.3.xsd">
    <id>server</id>
    <formats>
        <format>zip</format>
    </formats>
    <fileSets>
        <fileSet>
            <directory>src/main/server/app1</directory>
            <outputDirectory>app1</outputDirectory>
        </fileSet>
    </fileSets>
    <files>
        <file>
            <source>src/main/common/server.xml</source>
            <outputDirectory>app1</outputDirectory>
        </file>
    </files>
    <!-- same configuration for app2 and 3 -->
</assembly>
```

---

If you want to do this in a loop (let's say you have 50 app folders), it is possible to generate the correct Maven assembly descriptor using a [Velocity template](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/devel/index.html). Invoking Velocity is done with the [`velocity-maven-plugin`](https://code.google.com/p/velocity-maven-plugin/).

Sample velocity template (save as `src/main/common/assembly-server.xml.vm`):

```
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.3" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.3 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.3.xsd">
    <id>server</id>
    <formats>
        <format>zip</format>
    </formats>
    <fileSets>
        #foreach($i in [1..50])
        <fileSet>
            <directory>src/main/server/app$i</directory>
            <outputDirectory>app$i</outputDirectory>
        </fileSet>
        #end
    </fileSets>
    <files>
        #foreach($i in [1..50])
        <file>
            <source>src/main/common/server.xml</source>
            <outputDirectory>app$i</outputDirectory>
        </file>
        #end
    </files>
</assembly>
```

Plugin configuration:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.googlecode.velocity-maven-plugin</groupId>
    <artifactId>velocity-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>generate-server-assembly<id>
            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>velocity</goal>
            <goals>
        <execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <templateFiles>
            <directory>/src/main/common</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>assembly-server.xml.vm</include>
            </includes>
        </templateFiles>
        <removeExtension>.vm</removeExtension>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

This will generate a `assembly-server.xml` file under `target` that you can use as a assembly descriptor for the `maven-assembly-plugin`.

Comment: There is no easy concept of for loop ?

Comment: @user2230605 Not directly. To solve this in the past, I used a Velocity template which generated the correct Maven assembly. If you want a sample configuration, I will update my answer.

Comment: Thanks please update. I am thinking to use sbt its easy to write plugins there.

Comment: @user2230605 Please upvote and accept this answer if it solved your problem.